# Best way to write an equation while explaining something in a paper

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

I have found it difficult sometimes to write properly an equation in the middle of some explanations on a research paper, for example:

> This can be rewritten by a change in parametrization *a* = *m* as,
> *E* = *ac*²
> which, then simplifies to,
> *E* = *a c* × *c*.

I have seen people writing it in different styles. In this one, I assume that the equations break the flow of the sentence. So, I usually put a full stop after explaining the entire sentence. So, the *w* in *which* in my example in lower case.

Is there a conventional way to write things like this that is considered more scientific?

Comment: This does not answer your question about the formatting, but your commas are misplaced. The correct placement is: ... $a = m$ as $$E = ac^2,$$ which then simplifies to $$E = a c \times c.$$ (Also note that you should not really use $$ to display math in Latex. But maybe you are only doing this for the sake of simplicity here.)

Comment: Is there supposed to be a "where" somewhere in your example? Regardless, to quote David Mermin in [*What's wrong with these equations?*, Physics Today 42 (10), 9–11 (1989);](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2811173), "Math Is Prose" so equations really shouldn't break the flow of sentences.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil yes, i use $$ only here because of the stack exchange environment. Surprisingly, it doesn't work on this particular forum. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @Anyon Thanks for the nice suggestion and reference. I will look into this. :)

Comment: @AdamPřenosil Should the comma and period be within the "$$"s?

Comment: @Chris_abc Yes, certainly you don't want to start the line after the displayed equation with a comma.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil Fair point! Best may be to write the comma as normal text, but within the "$$"s, since the comma is not a part of the actual equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You treat mathematical equations like regular parts of prose.  As a rule of thumb, your surrounding prose and formatting should be just as it would be if you replace all your equations with [thing].  If we do this we will see that your commas are all over the place and make for an awkward pacing of your sentence:

> This can be rewritten by a change in parametrization [thing] as, [thing] which, then simplifies to, [thing].

A much better form would be:

> This can be rewritten by a change in parametrization [thing] as [thing], which then simplifies to [thing].

Another thing to bear in mind is that modern mathematics can lean heavily on the benefits of standard mathematical notation making use of the [transitivity of equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) to give clear sequences of steps in a succinct notational form.  While ancient mathematicians tended to present mathematical steps and implications using more prose, we can write them in a very succinct way like this:

> Taking [thing] gives [thing].

For your particular case, you could write:

> Taking $a=m$ gives
> $$E = mc^2 = ac^2 = ac \times c.$$